# Can I fit a 90" dining table plus 8 chairs in an 11' ford cargo van?

Tags: construction, hardware, load, transportation

I'm trying to figure out what size van I need to move a 90" dining table plus 8 chairs, the 2 table legs can be detached from table top for transport: [image] [image]

The van has 11 feet of cargo space

Height of Cargo Area: 4’ 5”
Width: 4’ 10”
Length: 11'

[image]

Will everything fit in one trip?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a math problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimensions of that table are  3' 9" wide and 7' 8" long. Turn the table top sideways and it will slide right into the van. Stack the chairs on top of each other seat-to-seat beside the table top from front to back. Slide the legs in between the legs of the chairs and it should all fit. You can probably place the chairs any way you like with the table sideways. That van has plenty of room.